# How should I understand "I will read pages that only weary me"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This is a quote from W. Somerset Maugham's *On Reading* as a text in our textbook. And the whole sentence look somewhat like the following:

> To know how to skip is to know how to read with profit and pleasure, but how you are to learn it I cannot tell you, for it is a trick I have never acquired. I am a bad skipper; I am afraid of missing something that may be of value to me, **and so will read pages that only weary me** [...].

Since the paragraph is talking about the skill of skipping, how to understand that he will only "read" pages that weary him rather than "skip" them?

I tried to google the original text but only found some quotes. Could it be a typing mistake of the publishing house?

Comment: I think you have misread/misplaced the word *only*.  He's not saying he will *only* read pages that weary him (i.e. and no others) but that he will dutifully read *all* pages including those that end up having no other affect than to weary him- for fear of missing some important tidbits they might have contained.

Comment: @Jim think you are right... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author says "it is a trick I have never acquired".  In this clause, *it* refers to *skipping*.  In other words, the author has never learned the skill of skipping.

The author says that learning to skip is a good thing.  But unfortunately he has never learned how to do it himself, so even if pages "only weary" him, he reads them anyway.

Comment: Thx and I think Jim has just pointed out what a stupid mistake I've made. ^-^

Comment: Not a "stupid mistake" at all. It's a difficult sentence. I believe what you mean is, "I think Jim has _cleared up my confusion"_  :-)